# Get state of soft input keyboard on Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have an `EditText` in my Android app, with a normal keyboard attached to it, e.g. there are no custom filters, or other restrictions set on it. I would like to find out if the user uses the `QWERTY` keyboard, or she switched to another type, for example to the one where the numbers are displayed, and other special characters. Is this possible?

Thanks.